# JSCH sudo navigating to protected directory

Tags: java, eclipse, ssh, jsch

Hey all I am new to SSH so this is probably an easy issue to solve. I am using the **[jcraft.jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sudo.java.html)** for Java and I am trying to log in (which it does) and then sudo to a protected directory called **output**.

Without Sudo I can visit all the way to **/export/home/scripts** without any problems (but that's another script and not this one).

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class Sudo {
public static void main(String[] arg){
      try {
          JSch jsch     = new JSch();
          String host   = null;

          if(arg.length>0){
            host=arg[0];
          }

          Session session = jsch.getSession("userDev", "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx", 22);
          session.setPassword("xxxxxxxxxxxx");
          java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
          config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
          session.setConfig(config);
          session.connect();

          String command    = "sudo cd /export/home/scripts/output";
          String sudo_pass  = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
          Channel channel   = session.openChannel("exec");

          ((ChannelExec) channel).setPty(true);

          // man sudo
          // -S The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the
          // standard input instead of the terminal device.
          // -p The -p (prompt) option allows you to override the default
          // password prompt and use a custom one.

          try (InputStream in=channel.getInputStream()) {
            try (OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream()) {
                ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);
                ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("sudo -S -p '' "+command);
                channel.connect();
                out.write((sudo_pass + "\n").getBytes());
                out.flush();

                byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];

                while (true) {
                    while (in.available() > 0) {
                        int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);

                        if (i < 0) {
                            break;
                        }

                        System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                    }

                    if (channel.isClosed()) {
                        System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                        break;
                    }

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception ee) {
                    }
                }

                channel.disconnect();
                session.disconnect();
            }
          }
      } catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e);
      }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> xxxxxxxxx <-password showing here
>
> sudo: cd: command not found
>
> exit-status: 1

So what would I be missing (or need to edit)?

**UPDATE 1**

Doing **sudo -i export/home/scripts/output** as second suggested in the link i get the following in the console:

> xxxxxxxxx <-password showing here
>
> cd
>
> -bash: /export/home/scripts/output: is a directory
>
> exit-status: 126

I have tried the following:

> sudo -i | cd /export/home/scripts/output
>
> sudo -S -p | cd /export/home/scripts/output
>
> sudo -i -S -p ''; cd /export/home/scripts/output;
>
> sudo -S -p ''; cd /export/home/scripts/output;
>
> sudo -i; cd /export/home/scripts/output
>
> sudo -S -p cd /export/home/scripts/output
>
> sudo -i cd /export/home/scripts/output
>
> sudo cd /export/home/scripts/output sudo -S -p ''
>
> sudo sh -c "cd /export/home/scripts/output"

Among others I'm sure that I just forgot I used since I've used so many.

Comment: Check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/291666/why-doesnt-sudo-cd-var-named-work

Comment: @second tried that just now and updated my OP with the results of that.

Comment: Wasn't it supposed to be something like this: `sudo -i | cd /export/home/scripts/output`

Comment: @second it tells me **bash: line 0: cd: /export/home/scripts/output: Permission denied** when typing what you have above.

Comment: Does it work when you execute the command directly on the machine using the user `userDev` ?

Comment: Yes. I use putty and it does work just fine there.

Comment: It just seems to output junk when i run that.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for trying second.

Comment: @Second I have added all that I can remember to the OP of the commands I have tried.

Comment: You should also list the results you've received for each of those commands.  By the way what is the `sudo -S -p '' ` supposed to do? The use of `;` was only because I read somewhere that multiline commands in `jsch` might need to be seperated by that characters. -- My guess is still its either a typo in the command or a permission problem.